# Cocos2d - apply GLImageProcessing effect to CCSprite

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

Apple's oplengl [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) loads an image and applies image adjustments: brightness, saturation, contrast, hue and sharpness.

How can GLImageProcessing be used on a CCSprite?

Any help would be appreciated!

---

Update:
Cocos2d v2 has shader support. For Image Effects look up GLSL shader called Photoshop Math.

---

Comment: Cocos2d-iphone gles 2.0 branch lets you apply Shaders!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've applied approach from GLImageProcessing to change the hue of CCSpite and wrote a subclass of CCSprite for convenient usage. Check this out: https://github.com/alex314/CCSpriteWithHue

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it could be better if you add a code sample also to the answer.

Comment: The repo I left a link to has a well crafted readme.md file which contain a code example, and the project itself is an example of usage the CCSpriteWithHue class

Answer (score 4):

Cocos2D is an Objective-C framework wrapping openGL plain C API.
GLImageProcessing Sample code is an example of using openGL.

To apply similar effects to a `CCSprite`, AFAIK, there is not hue, brightness or such image processing effects into Cocos2D. So I would suggest to override CCSprite and code your own drawing, inspiring from GLImageProcessing.

The interesting entry points are, for `CCSprite` :

```
-(void) draw
```

Which is responsible of openGL drawing of you sprite.

For `GLImageProcessing` :

```
 void drawGL(int wide, int high, float val, int mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several discussions to implement like GLImageProcessing with cocos2d. You can call any GL API in cocos2d.

- [texture modulation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14505)
- [Using a texture combiner to render CCSprite in greyscale?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10227)
- [Gaussian BLUR implemented in cocos2d!](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6315)