# Cocos2D: increasing Sprite Brightness

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a good way to adjust the brightness of a CCSprite without using an overlay sprite or creating a separate texture? The color property doesn't work since it can only decrease the brightness.

I am thinking this is possible by overriding the draw method and adding some opengl calls similar to what is found in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html , but all of my attempts have failed and I am very novice at writing raw opengl. Does anyone know if this is possible and what calls need to be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not the same as brightness, it would be more bright.

```
[sprite setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE}];
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, but I think its as close as cocos2d is capable of.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664706/cocos2d-apply-glimageprocessing-effect-to-ccsprite/5559084#5559084)?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [sprite setOpacity: 127] to dim it.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of opacity. I am actually specifically trying to make the sprite brighter as opposed to darker.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "lightening" the sprite by using

```
char moreBright = 24;
[sprite runAction:[CCTintBy actionWithDuration:0.0f red:moreBright green:moreBright blue:moreBright]];
```

Comment: Won't work; by default the sprite is already at it's brightest.